# Создать файл при помощь javascript

Tags: javascript

Как создать файл при помощи javascript и записать в него 2 переменные?

Файл должен ложиться в ту же дерикторию, в которой лежит сайт. Например http://gggg.com/txter.txt 
Запись переменных:
Переменная `А=1111111;`
Переменная `B=2222222;`

Переменная А должна быть записана в файл 1 раз при его создании.
Переменная В должна дописываться в конец при каждом исполнении скрипта.

Скрипт должен проверять, существует файл или нет. Если не существует, то создавать его и записывать в него переменную А. Если файл существует, то просто дописать в его конец переменную В.
Каждая запись должна идти с новой строки.

Comment: Речь ведь о node.js?

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/servguide14/jsserv.html#1028568

Comment: Без серверной части + AJAX никак

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток!

Без использования ActiveX или каких либо плагинов создание файла невозможно. JavaScript не имеет доступ к файловой системы, это сделано в целях безопасности.