# javascript создание файлов на стороне клиента без участия сервера

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript можно реализовать создание файлов, есть вот такая html структура. Смысл в том что при выборе, создается текстовый документ, по указанному пути.

```
<body>
<H2>Путь создания файлов</H2>
<form name="form1">
    <input text="text" size="40" value="D:\\textfile.txt" name="pole">
    <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ONCLICK="f1(frm1.pole.value)" VALUE="Создать файл">
</form>
<H2>Какие создать файлы</H2>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="total" value="checkbox" onClick="checkAll(this.form,'checkbox[]',this.checked)">Отметить все
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="checkbox">Heder
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="checkbox">Footer
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="checkbox">SidBar
</form>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создать файл при помощь javascript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459641/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-javascript)

Comment: @ДенисФедичкин, а там разве есть принятый ответ?

Comment: да я смотрел его, но решил еще раз задать его потому что наткнулся вот на это http://it.kgsu.ru/JS/js0062.html

Comment: @ДенисФедичкин, не дубликат - там хотят файл на сервере, а тут - на клиенте.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там тоже хотели на клиенте

Comment: @ДенисФедичкин, "Файл должен ложиться в ту же дерикторию, в которой лежит сайт." - и в какой же дириктории на клиенте лежит сайт? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, не выдирайте из контекста. Там было ясно сказано, что хотят создать файл при помощи JavaScript

Comment: @ДенисФедичкин, тут есть целая метка javascript, но это не делает вопросы по ней одинаковыми.

Comment: Мужики, я не хотел повторяться, если бы не та статья, вот и все..... хотел спросить гуру.... кто лучше понимает меня. Вот гляньте ее а потом спорьте..... че до как, а там реально человек на серваке хотел создавать, а я на клиенте или без сервака сказать так.

Comment: @Stasinskii в статье по вашей ссылке используется [`ActiveXObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) – проприетарная устаревшая (?) технология от Microsoft, работающая только в IE под Windows, от использования которой лучше воздержаться.

Comment: На Nodejs  сайт? Если для хранения инфы то можно юзать БД на клиенте

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду делать через  Node.js уже решил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из чистого JavaScript в браузере файл можно только **скачать** – через диалог Сохранения файла. Помимо упомянутых @Дмитрий-Никитин [способов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463262/7161), есть ещё [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) поддерживаемый современными браузерами, который предпочтителен при объёмах данных больше нескольких мегабайт.

Если вам это нужно исключительно локально, и программировать хочется только на JavaScript – вариант поставить локально [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) – он умеет создавать локальные файлы через [Filesystem API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html), например (код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)):

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('D:\\textfile.txt', "Превед", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("Файл сохранён.");
});
```

Comment: ооо спасибо, думаю будет хорошим решением, потому что уже стоит  Node.js

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript выполняется в браузере, отправить файл на скачивание можно двумя способами:

1. base64-encoded контентом, например:
   `window.location.href =
   'data:application/octet-stream;base64,...'`

   Которая будет обрабатываться браузером в соотвествии с настройками программ по
   умолчанию
2. Аттрибутом download http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: это тогда если у меня 10 файлов на создании то я их буду всех скачивать? мне нужно чтоб я это не видел, все тихо создалось....

Comment: Зловреды были бы очень рады такой возможности.

Comment: @Sergiks мне кажется он и есть тот самый зловред

Answer (score -2):

На `JavaScript` вы никак файл и нигде не создадите, это скриптовый язык с исполнением на клиентской стороне. Если вы хотите создать файл на сервере, то можно использовать связку с `PHP`

Comment: а есть чтоб без сервера работала? нарвался на эту статью http://it.kgsu.ru/JS/js0062.html но что то не работает.

Comment: @Stasinskii вы где хотите файл создать?

Comment: Локально на компьютере но без участия сервера. Хочу облегчить рутинную работу.

Comment: Локального на компьютере вряд ли, может быть есть какой то плагин для какого нибудь браузера, но вообще это нарушает правила безопасности, используйте для этого другие инструменты и ЯП

Comment: получается это только полноценные языки, типа java.... по другому нельзя.

Comment: Ну можно только на скачивание отправить файл, но лучше да, либо `Java` аплет либо вообще другой подход

Comment: спасибо, а на java не подскажете куда от чего оттолкнуться?

Comment: думаю можно с google, первое что нашел – http://web.mit.edu/javadev/doc/tutorial/getStarted/applet/index.html

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!