# Помощь с работай с файловой системой Javascript

Tags: javascript, файлы, файловая-система

Я никогда не занимался web-ом, но сейчас мне потребовалось сделать систему контроля пришедших людей на мероприятие. Я написал вот такой сайт, доступный только через наш Wifi при помощи `python3 -m http.server"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
Из - за низкой скорости соединения загружена лёгкая версия <br>
Input vaucher code 
<form name="search">
    <input type="text" name="key"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" />
</form>
<script>
function sendForm(e){
     
    // получаем значение поля key
    var keyBox = document.search.key;
    var val = keyBox.value;
    if(val.length < 4){
        alert("Недопустимый код. Попробуйте еще раз.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    else
        alert("Спасибо за регистрацию.");
}
 
var sendButton = document.search.send;
sendButton.addEventListener("click", sendForm);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я хочу что бы после регистрации код ваучера сохранялся в текстовый файлик (?Базу данных) на соем сервере и я бы мог в любой момент его посмотреть. Я понимаю что система довольно идиотская, но я хотел бы получить результат как можно быстрее, так как сильно ограничен во времяни.

По запросу File System JS находит принципы работы с файловой системой клиента. Можете подсказать в какую сторону копать. находил вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459641/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-javascript) вопрос, но я почти точно уверен что как то можно решить мою проблему минимальными силами.

Comment: Ничего не понял =). При чём тут file system? Это модуль в node.js. Вы написали, что ваш сайт на python. Какая здесь взаимосвязь?)

Comment: по факту регистрации отправляете запрос на сервер, в обработчике данного запроса сохраняете что надо.

Comment: И искал как работать с файловой системой

Answer (score 0):

Если вам удобнее писать на js -- возьмите сервер с поддержкой js,
например node.js + express:

https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/installing.html

Сервер должен отдавать ваш статический хтмл.

Вам надо посылать запрос с браузера на сервер (смотрите `fetch`-`POST`).

Сделать на сервере обработчик.

И смотрите, как в node.js работать с fs.